# perl user input into a data structure

Tags: perl

I am trying to take user input such as 4 2 1 4 and store that into an array. Then loop through the array looking for duplicates to store into a hash table.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
print "Enter numbers into hash table :";

my @num = <STDIN>;
my %hash;

foreach $x (@num){
    my $count =1;
    foreach $y(@num){

        if($x == $y){  
        my $count++;
        $hash{'$x'} = $count;
        }
    }

}

map{print "$_\t$hash{$_}\n"}keys %hash;
```

I expect the result to be:
1 1
2 1
4 2

The actual result, I just continue to enter digits, after I hit enter the program continues to ask for more input. I hit CTRL D and nothing happens.

Comment: Your `'$x'` is a literal `$x`, not the value of the `$x` variable. The single quotes `''` do not interpolate. Get rid of the `''`. And your code is overly complicated. To count them, it's enough to iterate once and count. You don't need to go through them one by one and compare. `my %counts; ++$count{$_} for @num;` will do. No need for  `$x` and `$y` at all. And don't forget to turn on `use strict` and `use warnings`! :)

Comment: How do you want to define then the user has finished entering values? The usual ways are to put them all on one line and split the input string, or to have a special value to enter which means the end of the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a great many problems with your code and I don't have time to explore them all

I hope it helps to offer you a working solution

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my %counts;

print "Enter numbers into counts table: ";

++$counts{$_} for split ' ', <STDIN>;

print "$_\t$counts{$_}\n" for keys %counts;
```

#### output

```
E:\Perl\source>count.pl
Enter numbers into counts table: 4 2 1 4
1       1
2       1
4       2
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually found an easier way, just using arrays.

Comment: @Nameishi: Easier? My answer has only four lines of code! If you have an answer then you really should post it here. You may then accept your own answer.

Comment: not easier than yours but easier than what I was trying to do.  Thanks Borodin

Comment: @Nameishi: *Please* post your solution here. It is important that you get used to writing answers as well as solutions. At worst you will get some ideas about how to improve your code.

Answer (score 2):

Probably it is possible to do more nicely, but i would do this as:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $numbers;

print "Enter numbers and finish with CTRL-D\n";
while(my $line = <STDIN>) {
        $numbers->{$_}++ for ( $line =~ m/(\b\d+\b)/g );
}

print Dumper $numbers;
```